# Move first item in array to be last

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'clientId',
        'clientId': SlicedCookie
    });
```

Question: How do I move '0' to be the last item in the array?

Answer (score 4):

[`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) the first element, and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it on to the end.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr.push(arr.shift());

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `window.dataLayer.push(window.dataLayer.shift());` This only works if I try it on the browser console, but doesn't when I try to add it inside the file.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting your data from a `fetch` maybe? You'll have to wait until the data has been received before you can perform the operation.

Comment: Yes, from google tag manager.

Comment: is there any other way of doing it instead of `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Not sure if these will help there is some documentation out there <waves hand at the internet>: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570076/detect-when-google-tag-manager-has-finished-loading-tags), and [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/notify-page-google-tag-manager-loaded/). I don't use GTM so I can be certain this will work.

Answer (score 1):

After having the full array, do this to move the first item to last:

```
window.dataLayer.push(window.dataLayer.splice(0,1)[0]);
```

Comment: Same issue, see my other comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't clear of your example but as I understand you could use `Array.prototype.splice` and `Array.prototype.push` for achieving this requirement.

```js
const data = [2, 3, 4, 5];
const item = data.splice(0, 1);
data.push(item[0]);

console.log(data);
```